# sql, employee and department

Tags: mysql, sql

Requirements: using one query only to show each department with their employee counts (two tables, department and employee); order by number of employees decreasing;(for departments with no employees, still show them); for departments with the same size, order by department name alphabetically. My solution not showing the departments with no employees, also, it is not showing alphabetically order of departments when same number of employees:

```
SELECT d.DEPT_ID,
    DEPT_NAME, COUNT(s.STUDENT_ID) as numStudents
    FROM Departments d, Students s
    WHERE d.DEPT_ID = s.DEPT_ID
    GROUP BY d.DEPT_ID
    ORDER BY numStudents DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN instead of the cross join you are currently doing.

```
SELECT d.DEPT_ID, 
d.DEPT_NAME, COALESCE(COUNT(s.STUDENT_ID),0) as numStudents
FROM Departments d, 
LEFT JOIN Students s
  ON s.dept_id = d.dept_id
GROUP BY d.DEPT_ID, d.dept_name
ORDER BY numStudents DESC, DEPT_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to show departments with no students, you have to use `LEFT JOIN`, not a cross product. And to order by name when they have the same number of students, you need to add that to your `ORDER BY` clause.

```
SELECT d.DEPT_ID, DEPT_NAME, IFNULL(COUNT(s.STUDENT_ID), 0) AS numStudents
FROM Departments AS d
LEFT JOIN Students AS s ON d.DEPT_ID = s.DEPT_ID
GROUP BY d.DEPT_ID
ORDER BY numStudents DESC, DEPT_NAME
```